# List Rails I18n strings with full keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, yaml

I'd like to be able to generate a complete list of all the I18n keys and values for a locale including the full keys. In other words if I have these files:

`config/locales/en.yml`

```
en:
  greeting:
    polite: "Good evening"
    informal: "What's up?"
```

`config/locales/second.en.yml`

```
en:
  farewell:
    polite: "Goodbye"
    informal: "Later"
```

I want the following output:

```
greeting.polite: "Good evening"
greeting.informal: "What's up?"
farewell.polite: "Goodbye"
farewell.informal: "Later"
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 7):

Once loaded into memory it's just a big Hash, which you can format any way you want. to access it you can do this:

```
I18n.backend.send(:translations)[:en]
```

To get a list of available translations (created by you or maybe by plugins and gems)

```
I18n.available_locales
```

Answer (score 5):

Nick Gorbikoff's answer was a start but did not emit the output I wanted as described in the question. I ended up writing my own script `get_translations` to do it, below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'pp'
require './config/environment.rb'

def print_translations(prefix, x)
  if x.is_a? Hash
    if (not prefix.empty?)
        prefix += "."
    end
    x.each {|key, value|
      print_translations(prefix + key.to_s, value)
    }
  else
      print prefix + ": "
      PP.singleline_pp x
      puts ""
  end
end

I18n.translate(:foo)
translations_hash = I18n.backend.send(:translations)
print_translations("", translations_hash)
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't have time to give you full code, so I just gave you a pointer. One more thing: check out awesome_print - it's much better than PrettyPrint gem IMHO. It is actually used by pry and irbtools for formatted outputs in console.

Comment: @NickGorbikoff no problem, I did appreciate the tip and it was a good contribution to the question. I will have to check out awesome_print.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working version of a method you can use to achieve your desired output

```
def print_tr(data,prefix="")
  if data.kind_of?(Hash)
    data.each do |key,value|
      print_tr(value, prefix.empty? ? key : "#{prefix}.#{key}")
    end
  else
    puts "#{prefix}: #{data}"
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
$ data = YAML.load_file('config/locales/second.en.yml')
$ print_tr(data)
=>

en.farewell.polite: "Goodbye"
en.farewell.informal: "Later"
```