# Rspec test if locales have the same keys

Tags: rspec, rails-i18n

Answering my own question here because I think this is probably useful to lots of people.

How can I have rspec verify that locales have the same keys so no translations are missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me with 2 locales but could be trivially adapted to work with more.

We convert the I18n data to a flat array like ['key', 'key.key', 'key.other_key'] and now we can check both arrays contain the same thing.

```
def print_tr(data, prefix = '')
  if data.kind_of?(Hash)
    results = data.map { |key, value| print_tr(value, prefix.empty? ? key : "#{prefix}.#{key}") }
    return results.flatten
  else
    return prefix
  end
end

RSpec.describe 'i18n' do
  it 'has same keys in both locales' do
    all_en = print_tr(I18n.t('.', locale: :en)).map(&:to_s).sort
    all_ja = print_tr(I18n.t('.', locale: :ja)).map(&:to_s).sort
    all_same = all_en == all_ja
    expect(all_same).to be_truthy
    unless all_same
      p 'Translations missing in ja'
      p all_en - all_ja
    end
  end
end
```

Adapted from this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/18324848/2558108